# Does bonus damage gained from magic item enhancements and implement properties stack?

Tags: dnd-4e

My level 10 Wizard has 2 + Int mod(+6) base damage for Magic Missile. If I add to that a Dragon-tooth wand of cold +2, will my Magic Missile damage become 11? **[2 + Int mod(+6) + 2 enhancement bonus + 1 deadly implement bonus]**

Also will Diabolic Transformation power give me +2 damage to my Magic Missile?

Comment: Can you provide a few more details (such as why you aren't sure if it applies and maybe the rules text for the item in question?)

Comment: Be aware that *magic missile* has been errataed to a very different version to cater to "magic missile always hits" 3.x edition fans. Which version are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the damage is 10.

The deadly property on the Dragontooth weapon *only* applies to *damage rolls.* Magic missile does not roll any dice and thus does not have a damage roll. The implement's enhancement damage applies because it applies to all damage done via spells cast with the implement (and magic missile explicitly calls this out). However, if a power/ability adds to "damage rolls" it does not apply to Magic Missile because Magic Missile does not have a damage roll.

Normally, these properties *would* stack, allowing the implement to provide +3 damage (+2 for enhancement, +1 for deadly). Additionally, the wand of cold's feature would *also* stack, so if you used this power with, say, ray of frost, you'd get +4 damage (+2 for enhancment, +1 for deadly, +1 for cold). The general rule in 4e is that untyped bonuses stack, and *same typed* bonuses to not stack. We're dealing with 2 untyped bonuses and 1 enhancement bonus, so they all stack.